# How to implement HMAC-SHA authentication from scratch?

Tags: security, authentication, language-agnostic, hmac

I would like to implement authentication for a web app api using a similar technique to the AWS Signature Process. The server will render html for user web browser clients. The app will also return json for non-browser clients (iphone, android, blackberry, ipad, etc.) I am trying to write authentication code that will allow a single user to be signed (remembered) in to the app from multiple clients. Logging out from any one client should not revoke the token/cookie for all the other clients.

1. When a user sign up or logs in, how does a client (native mobile client or web browser especially) get the private/secret key? My understanding is the key should not be sent over a network? Can it just be sent over ssl?
2. For browser clients is the private key stored in a cookie or in some other form of local storage?? I.e. for generic api token authentication would the token be stored in a cookie on the browser and in a db on the phone
3. When the client is a browser, how does it sign a request signature with private key? i.e. generate a hash of the id + private key + request. For native mobile clients or server to server communication I believe there are libraries that can be used to generate a signed request. When the request originates from a browser how does this work?
4. If a user is required to be remembered on multiple clients (tablet, iphone, work computer, home laptop, etc.) would the user need to have a set of private keys/tokens for each client?

I would have used Devise with Rails but it requires you to write your own token authentication code.

I am also looking at OAuth, which questions 2 and 4 both apply to, but would really like to investigate the AWS method.

Comment: Can you please start with an introductory paragraph with the scenario you're talking about, instead of jumping right into questions without context? It's not really clear to me what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You start with a solution (HMAC) but I do not think your "problem" fits your solution :).

I'll try to answer this to the best of my knowledge.

1. To my understanding ,a private key would be derived of a public key that is shared. Or you could share a private key, but only if authentication is already established (in other words: you already know for sure who you are talking to) and the connection is secured (encrypted). You still will be vulnerable to man in the middle attacks though.
2. I'm not sure. A cookie is not secure. Steal the cookie, steal the private key. My preference would be a locally stored key(file or storage), *encrypted by a password*.
3. You would have to devise some sort of a client side library (in javascript or something like it).
4. Yes.

Why share keys when you could share a token, like oAuth implements. The token is generated by your application and is valid for a limited time. This way you share access, but not the means to aquire access to your application. You login with username and password (or keyfile) and you get a token that grants you access untill the token is revoked.